# Weird error in Vue.js 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://api.ciuvo.com/api/analyze?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&version=2.1.4&tag=threesixty&uuid=8B61AA73-3715-4EE1-95DD-65ED24AFC1CC'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Everything was okay, but suddenly I am getting this error on my vue.js project today.
Anyone knows why?

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` - that's why.

Comment: `Everything was okay, but suddenly I am getting this error` what changed? specifically, what did YOU change between when everything was OK and now

Comment: I didn't change anything other than htmls!

Comment: Add this before your URL to avoid CORS: [https://corsproxy.io/?](https://corsproxy.io/?)

Comment: @Jordy - bad advice - one day, they'll start charging, or putting some limit on it, or completely disappearing, then the problem comes back

Comment: I didn't have to read any further than [_"Ciuvo is a **browser add-on**..."_](https://api.ciuvo.com/en/). Been playing around with your browser extensions lately perhaps?

Comment: well, something changed - what's the HTTP status for that request

Comment: @MohammadKhalilzadeh Take the time to read and understand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood, this error message indicates that your Vue.js application is trying to make a request to a domain (`https://api.ciuvo.com`) that is different from the one where your application is hosted (`http://localhost:8080`). This violates the same-origin policy enforced by web browsers to protect users’ security.

To solve this issue, you need to add the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the `server-side response` to allow requests from the origin of your Vue.js application.

However, since you don’t have control over the `https://api.ciuvo.com` server, you can use a workaround by using a proxy server to forward requests from your Vue.js application to the target `API server`.

One solution is to use the `http-proxy-middleware` package to set up a proxy in your Vue.js project. Here is the link to the package with installation guide [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware)
.

Then in your vuejs config file called : `vue.config.js` add something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://api.ciuvo.com',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api': '/api/analyze'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But you should also read it docs if something goes wrong or for a better understanding of it `api`.
This configuration tells the Vue.js development server to forward any requests with the `/api` prefix to `https://api.ciuvo.com/api/analyze`. The `changeOrigin` option changes the `Origin header` of the request to the target server’s domain, and `pathRewrite` option removes the `/api prefix` from the forwarded request.
In your Vue.js code, you can now make requests to `/api` instead of the target server URL.

If your using `fetch api` or `axios` you can do something like this:
`fetch('/api?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&version=2.1.4&tag=threesixty&uuid=8B61AA73-3715-4EE1-95DD-65ED24AFC1CC')`

or

`axios.get('/api?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&version=2.1.4&tag=threesixty&uuid=8B61AA73-3715-4EE1-95DD-65ED24AFC1CC')`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In case you send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, remove this and try again.

In server side must allow client to send this header, if you have access already, add this header to your request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

Comment: I'm not sending any requests. As soon as the html page loads and elements appear, this error appears and elements disappear!

Comment: I'm not sending any errors to API. This error occurs as soon as I enter my 'http://localhost:8080/<page>' address in my front-end

Comment: If you open element url in the browser, can you see any content?

Comment: The page loads for a few seconds, but as soon as the error occurs the page is blank!

Comment: Your url is not valid, and your question sis not about cross origin, you cant use your localhost url to checking by online analysis website.

Comment: Negative score for what? Ok good